# Pass Object as a Parameter to ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

How can I pass an additional parameter?

Here is some sample code to try and make it clear on what I want to do:

```
public class A {

    public static void create(String txt, ActionListener evt){
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(txt);
        SomeClass sample_class = new SomeClass();

        // Would like to do this...
        // item.addActionListener(evt, sample_class);

        item.addActionListener(evt);
    }

}

public class B {

    public static void init(){
        A.create("Test", evt -> {
            System.out.println("hi");
        });
    }

}
```

What I would like to do, is pass the "sample_class" so the action listener can use it.

So the end result would be like this, so I can use my class in the listener...

```
A.create("Test", (evt, something) -> {
    something.do_something();
});
```

Have read quite a few questions similar to this, but I can't wrap my ahead around it.

Comment: You don't need to add an extra parameter, just create a class that implements ActionListener and set whatever member variables you like in it.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Makes sense.  I suppose I can't use a Lambda now though, can I?

Comment: "I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail" - Abraham Maslow

Comment: If there's some reason you need to include a lambda in your code, include that requirement in the question

Comment: No reason, just asking.  Still learning, so wanted to be sure if I can or cannot use them with your solution above.  I've implemented your solution and setting member variables, which seems to be working fine.  Thanks.  Edit: Not sure how to accept your answer in the above comment, but that's what I used, and is working.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement ActionListener in your SomeClass and encapsulate your event in it.

```
public class A {
    public static void create(String txt, ActionListener evt){
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(txt);
        SomeClass sample_class = new SomeClass(evt);

        item.addActionListener(sample_class);
    }    
}

public class SomeClass implements ActionListener {
    ActionListener evt;

    public SomeClass(ActionListener evt) {
        this.evt = evt;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        this.evt.actionPerformed(ae);
    }
}
```